# Unfold musical jumps

Tags: code-golf, music

The *[Dal Segno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dal_Segno)* and *[Da Capo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_capo)* are two very commonly used musical terms. They mean "*from the sign*" () and "*from the beginning*" respectively.

There is also the idea of the *[coda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coda_(music))* (), which is the very end of a piece of music. It's what's played after the "main section" of the piece.

A *D.S. al coda* (*Dal Segno al coda*), for example, means "go to the *segno*, play until you're told to go to the *coda*, and then jump there."

### Description

Your job in this challenge is to take input composed of any number of notes which may or may not contain *Dal Segno*s and *Da Capo*s and output the same music with the aforementioned jumps "unfolded" so that the repetitions are expanded out verbatim.

### Input

Your code should take as input a sequence of either notes or *signals* (here defined as anything but a note), separated by spaces in one string.

- Notes are any of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, or `g`, with an optional `#` or `b` appended (for the purposes of this challenge, there is no rhythm).
- A `C` (capital c) represents a *coda* marking. There will always be either zero or two *coda* markings; the first *coda* marking represents where to jump from, and the second represents where to jump to.
- An `S` (capital s) represents a *signo* marking. There will always be either zero or one *signo* marking(s).
- An `F` (capital f) represents a *fine* marking. This "overrides" the end of the piece—more on that below. There will always be either zero or one *fine* marking(s).
- Any of the following exact strings of text represent:

  - `D.S. al fine`: go to the *signo* and play until either the end of the piece or the *fine* marking (if it exists).
  - `D.S. al coda`: go to the *signo*, play until the *coda*, then jump to the second *coda* marking and play until the end of the piece.
  - `D.C. al fine`: go to the beginning, play until the end or the *fine* marking.
  - `D.C. al coda`: go to the beginning, play until the *coda*, then jump to the second *coda* marking and play until the end of the piece.

  There will always be a minimum of zero and a maximum of one of each string per piece. There will never be multiple `al fine`s or multiple `al coda`s in a piece.

### Output

Your code should output in a similar string format: a list of notes, separated by spaces.

You may always assume that the output will end up being one or more characters long.

### Test cases

In: `a# bb c b a`
Out: `a# bb c b a`

In: `a S b D.S. al fine c`
Out: `a b b c`

In: `a S b C c D.S. al coda d C e`
Out: `a b c b e`

In: `a b F c d D.C. al fine e f`
Out: `a b c d a b`

In: `a b D.C. al fine c d F e f`
Out: `a b a b c d`

In: `a b C c d D.C. al coda e f C g g#`
Out: `a b c d a b g g#`

In: `a b D.C. al coda c d C e f C g g#`
Out: `a b a b c d g g#`

In: `a b S c d C D.C. al coda C D.S. al fine e f F g`
Out: `a b c d a b c d c d e f`

In: `a S b C c D.S. al coda C d D.S. al fine e F f`
Out: `a b c b d b c d e`

In: `a b C c d D.C. al coda e f F g g# C gb a# D.C. al fine`
Out: `a b c d a b gb a# a b c d e f`

In: `a F b C D.C. al coda C D.C. al fine`
Out: `a b a b a`

In: `C a S b D.C. al coda C c D.S. al fine d`
Out: `a b c b c d`

In: `a S b D.S. al coda C C c D.C. al fine`
Out: `a b b c a b c`

In: `a F C b C D.C. al coda D.C. al fine`
Out: `a b a a`

### Rules

- The markings will always appear in a logical order. That is, there will never be an `S` after a `D.S.` and there will always be one before, etc.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes will win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 253 bytes

```js
x=>eval('n=(" "+x).replace(/D.{11}|[CSF]/g,d=>({C:4,S:5,F:6}[d]|(d[2]<"S")*2+(d[8]<"f"))).split` `;for(i=c=f=o="";v=n[++i];v<9?v<4?(n[i]=7,i=0,s=n.indexOf`5`,v==0?f=i=s:v==1?c=i=s:v==2?f=1:c=1):v==4&c?c=!(i=n.indexOf("4",i+1)):v==6&f?i=n:0:o+=v+" ");o')
```

### Explanation

Could be golfed better but I'm done for now.

```js
x=>
  eval(`                                  // use eval to enable for loop without return
    n=(" "+x)                             // n = array of [ "", ...notes/commands ]
                                          // empty first element means f and c can be set
                                          //     to i (always true) in the cases below
      // DS fine => 0, DS coda => 1, DC fine => 2, DC coda => 3, C => 4, S => 5, F => 6
      .replace(/D.{11}|[CSF]/g,d=>({C:4,S:5,F:6}[d]|(d[2]<"S")*2+(d[8]<"f")))
      .split\` \`;
    for(
      i=                                  // i = position in note array
      c=                                  // c = look out for coda if true
      f=                                  // f = look out for fine if true
      o="";                               // o = output string
      v=n[++i];                           // v = note/command
      v<9?                                // if not a note
        v<4?(                             // if DS/DC
          n[i]=7,                         // change it to NOP
          i=0,                            // reset i here to save doing it in DC cases
          s=n.indexOf\`5\`,
          v==0?f=i=s:                     // case: D.S. al fine
          v==1?c=i=s:                     // case: D.S. al coda
          v==2?f=1:                       // case: D.C. al fine
          c=1                             // case: D.C. al coda
        ):
        v==4&c?c=!(i=n.indexOf("4",i+1)): // case: C
        v==6&f?i=n:                       // case: F
        0                                 // case: S
      :o+=v+" "                           // add the note
    );o                                   // return the output
  `)
```

### Test

```js
var solution = x=>eval('n=(" "+x).replace(/D.{11}|[CSF]/g,d=>({C:4,S:5,F:6}[d]|(d[2]<"S")*2+(d[8]<"f"))).split` `;for(i=c=f=o="";v=n[++i];v<9?v<4?(n[i]=7,i=0,s=n.indexOf`5`,v==0?f=i=s:v==1?c=i=s:v==2?f=1:c=1):v==4&c?c=!(i=n.indexOf("4",i+1)):v==6&f?i=n:0:o+=v+" ");o')
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="a b C c d D.C. al coda e f F g g# C gb a# D.C. al fine" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```